# [RobotFramework][selenium] browser open not working

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I`m new to **robot framework** and have some issues with **browser open**.

using:
python 3.7
RIDE 1.7.3.1

**This comes from RIDE:**

> Starting test: F-Project.Testsuite.test1
>   20190123 16:45:27.423 :  INFO : Opening browser 'gc' to base url 'https://bew.bestsofia.org/'.
>   20190123 16:45:31.656 :  INFO : Cannot capture screenshot because no browser is open.
>   20190123 16:45:31.659 :  FAIL : 
>   SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
>   from disconnected: unable to send message to renderer
>     (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)

Ending test:   F-Project.Testsuite.test1

**And this is printed form cmd:**

> DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58356/devtools/browser/c1b27833-83d7-44fd-ad08-c8fbffa9ee0a
>   wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "GetEventHandler() == this" failed at ....\src\common\wincmn.cpp(478) in wxWindowBase::~wxWindowBase(): any pushed event handlers must have been removed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> SystemError:  returned a result with an error set

---

I have tried different driver versions, but the problem doesn`t go.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: please add code trials for which you getting this error

Comment: Have you tried running the test from the command line to see whether or not it's a problem specific to RIDE?

Comment: As highlighted by @BryanOakley please provide more details on your setup and start by reducing any components not strictly needed. This includes Ride (As it is an editor that creates a command line command to execute the tests using Robot Frawework. Also add details on your browser brand, version, WebDriver Version,  Python Modules: Selenium, SeleniumLibrary and Robot Framework versions.